# Can I specify a database name dynamically in a trigger?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I need to get data from a table in a database who's database name will be determined as a variable during a trigger.  I then, knowing this variable need to get a seqno from a table in the determined database for a item which was also determined as a variable during a trigger.
I am trying this route as I assume I need to build the SQL statement before I set it to a variable.
This is not working and I need to know the best way on how I can do this:

```
DECLARE @SU_SEQNO INTEGER, @SU_NAME VARCHAR(50), @SU_OWNER VARCHAR(15), @SUD_SEQNO INTEGER, @SQL NVARCHAR(500)

SET @SU_OWNER = 'XXX'
SET @SU_NAME = '1ABC234'

SET @SQL ='SELECT @SUD_SEQNO=SEQNO FROM ' + (@SU_OWNER) + '.SU_MAIN 
              WHERE UNITNAME= ' + @SU_NAME 
SET @SUD_SEQNO = (EXECUTE (@SQL))
```

Thanks alot for any help with this

Comment: Is this in MS SQL Server?

Comment: "during a trigger" - I'd usually recommend against accessing *anything* outside of the current database during a trigger. It's usually better to queue such activity (using e.g. a table for the queue or server broker) and not prolong the original transaction too long. Also, related to triggers, the presence of scalar variables usually points to an issue where the author isn't aware that `inserted` and `deleted` can contain *multiple* rows (or zero rows)

Answer (score 0):

From: [Get result from dynamic SQL in stored procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10298654/get-result-from-dynamic-sql-in-stored-procedure)

```
SET @SQL = N'SELECT DISTINCT @FiscalYear = FiscalYear FROM ' + @DataSource;
EXEC sp_executesql @SQL, N'@FiscalYear INT OUTPUT', @FiscalYear OUTPUT;

PRINT @FiscalYear;
```

I'd re-engineer to use the sp_executesql method as shown above.  That should do the trick.

Comment: Thanks for that, and i have re-engineered it, but I am confused as to how to use sp_executesql.  My code is:

Answer (score 0):

I have amended the code, and it works

```
declare @su_owner varchar(15) = 'DBTEST'
declare @SU_SEQNO INTEGER=1, @SUD_SEQNO INTEGER=0, @SQL NVARCHAR(500)
DECLARE @ParmDefinition NVARCHAR(500), @SU_NAME_INPUT VARCHAR(50)='SU123'

SET @SU_NAME_INPUT = (SELECT UNITNAME FROM SU_MAIN WHERE SEQNO=@SU_SEQNO)
SET @SU_NAME = (SELECT UNITNAME FROM SU_MAIN WHERE SEQNO=@SU_SEQNO)

SET @SQL = N'SELECT @sud_seqnoOUT=MAX(SEQNO) FROM ' + quotename(@su_owner) + '.[dbo].[SU_MAIN] WHERE UNITNAME]=@SU_NAME_INPUT' ;

SET @ParmDefinition = N'@SU_NAME_INPUT VARCHAR(50),@sud_seqnoOUT INT OUTPUT'

EXEC sp_executesql @SQL,@ParmDefinition,@SU_NAME_INPUT = @SU_NAME,
            @sud_seqnoOUT = @SUD_SEQNO OUTPUT
```